# Config a Slim site in Apache but can't find .htaccess

Tags: apache, virtualhost, slim

I have built a PHP Slim app under `/home/tr/api`. All is well, if I start the server by `symfony server:start` and access it via `localhost:8000`.

I created a virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName api
        ServerAdmin master@rsywx.net

        DocumentRoot /home/tr/api/public
        <Directory />
                AllowOverride all
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/tr/api/public>
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api.error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And created a `.htaccess` file under `/home/tr/api/public` as below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Of course, I mapped `api` to `127.0.0.1` in the hosts file.

Then I tried to access the site in my browser but it gives me "Forbidden: You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe".

I looked at the log file and found the following line confusing:

```
[Sun Dec 24 19:30:34.753938 2023] [core:crit] [pid 681] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:54368] AH00529: /home/tr/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/home/tr/' is executable
```

It is very confusing because it seems the server is trying to find a .htaccess file in /home/tr, instead of `/home/tr/api/public` as specified in my vhost config file.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

It is the permission issue related to my virtual box. After setting `755` to my `/home/tr/` it works fine now.